# Magento multiple stores

Tags: php, database, magento, dns

Let's say I have two domains **www.store1.com** and **www.store2.com**, owned by two different companies, but on the same server and with the same code running.
Is it possible for Magento to load a completely different store based on the `SERVER_NAME` from which the request is coming?

Answer (score 0):

The main future of magento is multi-store. You can setup multi store by in same domain or sub-domains or multi-domains..For more info please go there..[LINK](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work)

You can configure multi store , multi site on the same server with single magento installation. But you should configure your store carefully. You need to configure your product, categories, inventories etc..for each store. Please follow this ***[Link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup).*** .

Comment: I already knew about the multi-store feature, but it's not what I'm searching for. The owners of the various store shouldn't even know they are hosted on the same server. Every store should use a different database one from the other, that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I am just confused with your question..Can you please explain me ..?

Comment: Ok sorry I try to be more clear. I will have two or more stores, hosted on the same server, with the same magento installation. Each store should have its own frontend and backend. Every store should be separated from the other, different product, users and admins. Is it possible to have this features on magento?